# CSS float not displaying properly

Tags: css

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npkbmr4s/).

```
<div style="width: 200px; position:relative;">
    <div style="float:left; width: 48%; background-color: green;">
        <p>Float1</p>
        <p>expanded</p>
        <p>expanded</p>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width:48%; background-color: blue;">
        <p>Float2</p>
        <p>expanded</p>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 48%; background-color: yellow;">
        <p>Float3</p>
        <p>expanded</p>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 48%; background-color: gray;">
        <p>Float4</p>
        <p>expanded</p>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 48%; background-color: red;">
        <p>Float5</p>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 48%; background-color: cyan;">
        <p>Float6</p>
        <p>expanded</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; border: none;">
</div>
```

I want to float the uneven numbered blocks to the left and the even ones on the right. Notice that blocks have variable heights. This should be the result:

```
Float1 Float2
Float3 Float4
Float5 Float6
```

Instead I got the Float3 element to the right because the Float2 is shorter than the Float1 (notice the misalignment with the correct items). Same thing is happening on Float6 displaying on the left.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? How can I fix that?

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using the [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/2008/07/22/multi-column-layout-with-css-and-jquery/) jQuery plugin. It appears to be a pretty and neat solution to my problem, since I can't edit the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to enclose each pair in a containing DIV or you will need to make them all the same height.

Comment: Containing each pair in a div causes blank spots under shorder divs

Comment: Of course.  But to have what you've asked for, this is what you'll need to do.  To have two columns, you'll have to put all of 1,3,5, etc in one div and 2,4,6 in another div and float the outer divs

Comment: Yeah, I've already thought that, but I can't. I must act via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not dividing the width of the parent evenly among the child divs. Make sure the sum of the widths of all the child containers don't exceed the width of the parent container. So for example, changing the widths of the child divs to 15% will line your divs horizontally, odd to the left and even to the right.

Comment: It's not about this. Widths are not exceeding the width of parent container. For example Float3 div has the same width of 1 and 5, but it displays to the right because the 2 is shorter than 1, not because of its width.

Comment: All your child divs currently have a width of 48%. So when the browser renders the divs, it will fill in almost half the space of the parent div (48% of 200px). Consequently, your divs are going to always stack. Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but if you want them all to fit horizontally with odds to the left and evens to the right, just reduce the size of your child divs like so: http://jsfiddle.net/npkbmr4s/3/

Comment: I don't want them to fit all orizzontally. I want to display the evens to the right and the odds to the left, in two columns. Like the scheme on main post.

Answer (score 0):

The upper two answers are somewhat logical and design patterns must be taken care of before actual designing. But, what to do after that. Here is a simple update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npkbmr4s/1/)

This is just a way around solution of your problem.

For example, instead of using `float`, use this

```
<div style="float:left; width: 48%; background-color: yellow;margin-right:5px">
```

i.e margin to cater for your intention.

Comment: well, that's a rough solution which will not work with dynamic contents.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using bootstrap? In Bootstrap v3.0 and up its exceedingly ease to make any columns structure that even degrades gracefully to mobile.

That being said, if you want it I will provide same Bootstrap column codes, if not here is another means  of CSS only completion of this schema. I have remove the inline styles as that gets messy very quickly and I have also segregated the boxes of each given side. If you use PHP or JQuery or JavaScript you can easy pull this DOM Manipulation off and move the evens to one side and the odds to the other side.

**CSS**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 1px;
}
.column {
    width: 48%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="width: 200px; position:relative;">
    <div class="column" style="float: left;">    
        <div style="background-color: green;">
            <p>Float1</p>
            <p>expanded</p>
            <p>expanded</p>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: yellow;">
            <p>Float3</p>
            <p>expanded</p>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: red;">
            <p>Float5</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="float: right;">    
        <div style="background-color: blue;">
            <p>Float2</p>
            <p>expanded</p>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: gray;">
            <p>Float4</p>
            <p>expanded</p>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: cyan;">
            <p>Float6</p>
            <p>expanded</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; border: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### flexible box model

The closest I've been able to get to this, whilst still keeping the original markup, is to use [flex box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) — which is explained here by [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), or here over at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

Here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sunckjyd/1/) of what I've got working, or if you prefer, here is an embedded snippet:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
     -moz-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
     -moz-align-items: flex-start;
      -ms-align-items: flex-start;
          align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
     -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
     -moz-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-justify-content: space-between;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.container > div {
  width: 46%;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  -webkit-align-self: stretch;
     -moz-align-self: stretch;
      -ms-align-self: stretch;
          align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="background-color: green;">
    <p>Float1</p>
    <p>expanded</p>
    <p>expanded</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: blue;">
    <p>Float2</p>
    <p>expanded</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: yellow;">
    <p>Float3</p>
    <p>expanded</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: gray;">
    <p>Float4</p>
    <p>expanded</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">
    <p>Float5</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: cyan;">
    <p>Float6</p>
    <p>expanded</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Three caveats:

1. Obviously flexbox is rather modern and so isn't that backwards compatible. I have tested in all the latest releases of popular browsers — Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari — not in Internet Explorer, however it should work in IE10+.
2. If you keep every item to its own height it isn't possible to avoid white gaps vertically (see the image below). However, with flexbox you can get the smaller item in each row to stretch to fill the remaining space using `align-self: stretch` *(left image without stretch, right with stretch)*. Whilst it is annoying you can't keep the items to their original height, this is at least one step better than having to hard-code fixed heights for two reasons.

   1. The smaller item will always automatically calculate its height comparative to whatever other item it sits besides (no need for manual css updates).
   2. The smaller item will automatically update its height (without any fiddling with js) if the size of the row ever changes dynamically (i.e. live in the page).
3. This will only work for even and odd items as you have described (or obviously inverted i.e. 1,3,5 being on the right), if you require any other kind of arbitrary pattern to shift left or right, this method will fail as it is relying on the row wrap after each even item.

[image: Showing the construct with and without align-self stretch enabled]